# How to have multiple products that depend on user input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am using the srmklive/laravel-paypal package for my paypal API.
Currently, in my view I have multiple instances of this code block with varying product ids

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PaypalController@expressCheckout']) !!}
          {{ Form::hidden('item', 1) }}
          {{ Form::hidden('name', 'm') }}
          {{ Form::hidden('price', 25) }}
          {{Form::submit('Pay via Paypal', array('class' => 'btn-info btn'))}}
          {!! Form::close() !!}
```

However, when I use this method with my getCart function,

```
         if($product == 1) {
          return [
           'items' => [
            [
             'name' => 'Mystery Core',
             'price' => 25,
             'qty' => 1,
            ],
           ],

            'return_url' => url('/paypal/express-checkout-success'),
            'invoice_id' => config('paypal.invoice_prefix') . '_' . $invoice_id,
            'invoice_description' => "Order #" . $invoice_id . " Invoice",
            'cancel_url' => url('/'),
            'total' => 25,
        ];
     }
}
```

the variables return null since they're coming from paypal's end, giving me a null error.
"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

How can I go about having multiple products? I have heard of the addOptions function but I cannot understand it.

Even a different package suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Which variables return null? Where and when do they return null?

Comment: @PrestonPHX $product returns null when paypal returns to expressCheckoutSuccess function after confirming payment

Comment: $product is not a PayPal variable

Comment: @PrestonPHX yes, that was mainly what I was asking about since the addOptions is poorly documented on the package page, hence my question on what variable to use!

Comment: PayPal will return an items array in the purchase_units[0]

Comment: @PrestonPHX will i be able to define this based on a request id? or how would i go about that? or even if you have a link to the documentation! so sorry for taking up so much of your time!

Comment: You are already attempting to set an items array, it seems. I don't know if your package is correctly mapping to what the PayPal API expects, but that specification is in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create